# How much do bricks cost at the LEGO Store?

Tags: minifigures, shopping, lego-store, pick-a-brick

I have never been to a LEGO Store, and I am hoping to go to one soon. I was wondering if anyone knew how much bricks cost at the LEGO Store? I want to buy some minifigs and some bricks. Do they sell the bricks by pound, or price per brick, or something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most common way to buy bricks from LEGO stores is by filling up a PaB cup:

[image: Large PaB cup]

There are two sizes of cups and occasionally other containers that can be filled during certain promotions. The large cup is $15.99 USD and the small cup is $8.99 USD currently. This isn't advertized, but you can also buy bricks in the boxes that they are shipped to the store in. These are $100 USD.

LEGO stores also typically allow you to build your own custom Minifigs. These include legs, torso, head, headgear, and an accessory. These are currently 3 for $9.99 USD.

Comment: Actually, a purchase from the Build-a-Mini tower only needs to total 15 pieces: the types don't matter. For instance, I bought my sister about 12 minifigure heads and a few other minifig parts as a gift, and the staff were totally fine with it. You're also allowed to change the individual torsos and pants to suit your liking. A double peg-legged set of legs, or a mermaid torso with hooks for hands are no problem!

Answer (score 4):

Pick-a-brick is a pretty cost effective to get bricks, in my experience. Prices will vary by your locale, of course, but I have one data point. For a 17 EUR PAB cup, I got around 100 EUR worth of bricks using BrickLink's average price. Since the average price is often above the median, and the median is not shown on the page, I instead recalculated using the price of the lowest lot with sufficient bricks (so if my cup contained 20 of part X I used the price of the cheapest X lot with >= 20 qty) an still the value was around 42 EUR.